# Mean minimum distance between two types of point particles (one type has N point particles whereas another has one) placed inside a square or a circle

Tags: probability, geometry, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

N red balls are distributed uniformly over a square of length L. One white ball is also placed within the square randomly. What is the average minimum distance between the white ball and a red ball?

How will the result change if the white ball is placed in the center of the square?

Instead of a square, if we consider a circle of radius R, how does the result change in both of the above mentioned cases (the white ball is placed somewhere inside the circle or in the centre) given the red balls are placed uniformly over the area of the circle?

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with the number of red balls. It's just the average distance from the white ball to a random point in the region. For a fixed position of the white ball that's an integral. For a random position it's an integral of an integral.

Comment: No. That is not the case. If the number of red balls are large, the probability of finding any of them will be higher as compared to the case where their numbers are less. Hence, the average distance from the while ball will very much depend on how many red balls are there in a particular area.

Comment: @tmitra if the number of red balls is big then there can be more red balls closer to the white ball, but it also means that can be more balls far away from the white ball. Therefore, the average distance will remain the same, regardless of the number of red balls.

Comment: @Bergson It will be the case for a very large N, which can be approximated as N red point particles occupying the whole square. In this case, it is just the average distance from the white ball to a random point in the region. This does not hold true, however, for a finite number of red balls. Say, the average distance is r from the white ball. Hence, in an area of pi x r x r (considering a disc of radius r), you will have atleast one red ball touching. Hence, in a crude approximation, pi x r x r/(L x L) = 1/N based on the probability of finding a red ball. So, r ~ 1/N^(1/2).

Comment: I think you are confusing the average distance to a red ball with the average minimum distance to a red ball. Your question asks about the former.The latter will indeed approach 0 as N grows.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks! You are correct.. My question is specifically about average minimum distance to a red ball. Editing the question accordingly.